# FastReport - Cant create individual charts for group bands

Tags: c#, .net, fastreport

I'm quite new to FastReport and am having some troubles trying to create a report with charts. The data comes from a list of objects representing readings from a temperature monitoring software that collects data from several points which are stored in a MySQL database and retrieved using EF Core . I'm trying to use the point ID as the grouping criterion to generate the temperature graphs for each point.

Here's the code I've used to retrieve the data:

```
List<CSQLModels.CHistory> hist = new List<CSQLModels.CHistory>();

        using (var db = new CSQLClient())
        {
            var startdate = datePickerStart.Value.Date + hourPickerStart.Value.TimeOfDay;
            var enddate = (datePickerEnd.Value.Date + hourPickerEnd.Value.TimeOfDay).AddDays(1);
            hist = await db.History
                          .Include(x => x.Point)
                          .Where(x => selectedIds.Contains(x.PointId) && x.Date >= startdate && x.Date < enddate)
                          .OrderBy(x => x.PointId)
                          .ThenBy(x => x.HistoryId)
                          .ToListAsync();
        }

        report1.RegisterData(hist, "readings",3);
```

I've used a group header to create separate data bands for each point and to add a chart (or sparkline) to each point's respective data band, which worked out so far. But linking the data to the charts either results in the charts being completely empty or every chart containing all of the data.

[The data I'm using is organized like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jKzF.png)

[The report structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z85iU.png)

[Data series settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brjHE.png)

[Chart properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlnBu.png)

If I dont set the filter property on the series to use the point ID then the chart is actually generated, but containing the data from all the points on every chart. Here 5, 6 and 7 are each point's ID, [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgMuk.png).

If I set the filter property to PointID the report ends up [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUe0Z.png).

I think I have iterated over all possible combinations of (at least to me) relevant property values for either the charts or group bands, if someone could help me it would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put Chart control into "**Footer**" band (that goes after "Data" band) or to "**Group Footer**" band....

In other bands MSChart control display default values :(  i thing this happens because control did not have result of calculation if placed before data bands.....

I have the same problem and Chart control, placed before table data did not display calculation result :( , but if i place it after "**Data**" band - everything is OK.

[image: bands to put MSChart control in FastReport]

For placing **MSChart** before "**Data**" possible use a "*dirty hack*":

In "AfterData" event of band, where MSChart placed and calculated charts, i am in code (runtime) change MSChart.**Parent** value for new band name where i want to place already calculated MSChart control:

```
private void DataFooter1_AfterData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  MSChart1.Parent = Child3;
}
```

NOTE: this hack hack change Parent to Next Control after current Parent :(